# If you drink a Potion of Invisibility, do you become visible if you are hit?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, attack, invisibility

If you drink a *Potion of Invisibility* and then are hit by someone, do you become visible?

I don't see anything in the PHB that says that. Neither do I see anything like that for someone that is hiding.

According to [Unseen Attackers and Targets](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#UnseenAttackersandTargets) (PHB p.194-195), you only give away your location when you attack:

> If you are hidden—both unseen and unheard—when you make an attack, you give away your location when the attack hits or misses.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Note that being hidden and invisible are two completely separate things. You can be hidden but not invisible, invisible but not hidden, or invisible and hidden at the same time. You should limit the question to the case you want to know about (invisible), and leave out the question about hidden - or have it as a separate question.

Comment: Is there something that makes you think that this would be a thing?  There seems to be an assumption that this is how it would be but you can't confirm it.

Answer (score 10):

#### Being hit does not end the invisibility granted by the Potion.

The description of the [*potion of invisibility*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/potion-of-invisibility) states:

> This potion's container looks empty but feels as though it holds liquid. When you drink it, you become invisible for 1 hour. Anything you wear or carry is invisible with you. **The effect ends early if you attack or cast a spell.**

The [invisible condition](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Invisible) ends under the circumstances stated above: when the creature that drank the potion attacks or casts a spell, being hit is not listed as an option.

---

There may be some situations that require a DM ruling: for example, you are fighting an invisible creature in a tavern and then you try to pour some  beer on the target. A DM may call an attack roll, and if you succeed in "hitting" the enemy their position may be somewhat more clear (again, up to the DM), but the invisible condition does not end. Anyway, since the beer is now on the target, the DM may rule that it becomes invisible too (see the Q&A "[Does picking up an item while under the effects of the Invisibility spell turn it invisible?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/77725/63061)").

Answer (score 3):

## No

From the [item description](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/potion-of-invisibility)

> The effect ends early if you attack or cast a spell.

So that's it. Things only do what they say they do, anything else would be a ruling or a house rule.

From the game world perspective, attacker only knows you were at this spot when he hit you and (if you are playing on a grid) that you are on the same 5 ft square if you didn't have a chance to move. That's it. You are still invisible, you are still unseen. Unheard requires a ruling, but I guess usually you're not, because hits tends to be loud.

---

Note that giving your position does not mean that you are visible. Enemy may know where you are, but still not see you.